# Proof of Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability, convergence

**Theorem**

Suppose $X_n \stackrel{P}\to X\quad \text{and}\quad Y_n \stackrel{P}\to Y $. Then $X_n+Y_n \stackrel{P}\to X+Y $.

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon >0 $ be given. Using the triangle inequality, we can write $$ | X_n-X|+|Y_n-Y| \geq |\left( X_n+Y_n \right) -\left( X+Y \right) | \geq \epsilon $$

Since **$P$ is monotove relative to set containment**, we have

$$ \begin{align} 
&P \left[| \left(X_n+Y_n \right)- \left(X+Y \right)| \geq \epsilon \right] \\ 
& \\
&\leq  P \left[|X_n-X|+|Y_n-Y| \geq \epsilon \right] \\
& \\
&\leq    P \left[|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon /2 \right]+P \left[|Y_n-Y|  \geq \epsilon/2 \right] \end{align} $$

Then by the hypothesis of the theorem the last two terms go to $0$ which gives us the desired result.

First of all sorry for the messy LaTeX notation, I did not know how to align those two inequalities in order for the second to appear right below the first, although I tried. My questions are what exactly does **"P is monotone relative to set containment"** mean and also how is the last inequality derived? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of *$P$ is monotone relative to set containment* is this:

> If $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A)\leq P(B)$.

Now here for every $\omega\in\Omega$, we have 
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \left\{\omega : \left| (X_n(\omega) + Y_n(\omega)) - ( X(\omega) + Y(\omega) ) \right| \geq \epsilon \right\}, \text{ and}\\
B &= \{ \omega : \left| X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) \right| + \left| Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right| \geq \epsilon \}.
\end{align*}$$

From your first inequality and for every $\omega\in\Omega$ and $\varepsilon >0$, we have

$$\left\{ \left| (X_n(\omega) + Y_n(\omega) - (X(\omega) + Y(\omega)) \right| \geq \varepsilon  \right\} \subseteq \left\{ \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)\right| + \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)\right| \geq \varepsilon \right\}.$$

So from the statement above

$$P\left( \left| (X_n(\omega) + Y_n(\omega) - (X(\omega) + Y(\omega)) \right| \geq \varepsilon \right) \leq P\left( \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)\right| + \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)\right| \geq \varepsilon \right).$$

To show the last inequality, first we prove that for every for every $\omega\in\Omega$ and $\varepsilon >0$ we have

$$\begin{multline*}
\{\omega : \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)\right| + \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)\right| \geq \varepsilon \}\\
\subseteq \{\omega : \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2\} \cup \{\omega : \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2\}.
\end{multline*}$$

This can be simply shown by contradiction, i.e. if

$$\{ \omega : \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) \right| < \varepsilon/2 \} \text{ and } \{\omega : \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right| < \varepsilon/2 \}$$

then we can sum them up to get $\{ \omega : \left|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)\right| + \left|Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)\right| < \varepsilon \}$, which is a contradiction.

Hence,
$$\begin{align*}
P\bigl( \{ \omega : &\left| X_n(\omega)-X(\omega) \right| + \left| Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right|\geq \varepsilon \} \bigr)\\
&\leq P\left( \{\omega : \left| X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2\} \cup \{\omega : \left| Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2 \} \right)\\
&\leq P\left( \{\omega : \left| X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2\}\right) + P\left( \{\omega : \left| Y_n(\omega) - Y(\omega) \right| \geq \varepsilon/2 \} \right),
\end{align*}$$
where the last inequality comes from $P(C \cup D) \leq P(C) + P(D)$. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you but could you also tell me how the last inequality is derived as well? I do not understand the $\epsilon/2$ inequalities.

Comment: Sure I can. But let me give you a hint maybe you can figure it out yourself first. Can you prove something like this: if $|C|+|D|\geq \epsilon$ then either $|C|\geq \epsilon/2$ or $|D|\geq \epsilon/2$. As for the 2nd hint: prove it by contradiction ;)

Comment: Well it seems trivial but I cannot prove it, I am just a beginner you see ;)

Comment: OK, I added some lines to complete the proof.

Comment: It is not clear how the contradiction shows that the one is the subset of the other.

Comment: (+1) I would just add that the argument for $x+y>\epsilon\Rightarrow (x>\epsilon/2 \;\mathrm{or}\; y>\epsilon/2)$ is more specifically named an argument by contraposition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: @Zen Your comment made it entirely clear. Thanks Zen

Answer (score 1):

If you're aware of an equivalent characterization of convergence in probability, the proof is really short.  It is known that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability if and only if, for any subsequence $\left \{a_1, a_2, \ldots \right\}$, there exists a sub-subsequence $\left\{a'_1,a'_2,\ldots \right \}$ such that $X_{a'_n} \rightarrow X$ almost surely.  This can be proven using the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Then, to show that $X_n + Y_n \rightarrow X + Y$ in probability, let $\left\{a_1,a_2,\ldots \right\}$ be an arbitrary subsequence.  By taking two successive subsequences of the $\left\{a_n\right\}$, we find a sub-sub-subsequence $\left\{a''_n\right\}$ such that $X_{a''_n} \rightarrow X$ and $Y_{a''_n} \rightarrow Y$, both almost surely.  From basic real analysis, $X_{a''_n} + Y_{a''_n} \rightarrow X + Y$ almost surely.  By the characterization, we know that $X_n + Y_n \rightarrow X + Y$ in probability.

Comment: Thank you but I am too much of a beginner to know that!Someday I hope!